# Angular Router Navigation Events, Do not Trigger for Absolute URL Clicks

Tags: angular, routes

Hi I have to clear some values when we are navigating from current page by clicking on a anchor link with absolute URL.

I tired using below router events, but this triggers only for relative URL's and not absolute URL's. Is there a way i can acheive this ?

```
this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter((event: Event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
        //perform some cleanup
      });
```

Comment: If you want to perform cleanup activity, why not do that in `ngOnDestroy()` hook. That hooks gets auto-triggered when you're moving from one component to another!

Comment: I want to clear some session values when I am navigating away from the page.

Comment: @Raji for every router change , Do you want to call some method ?

Comment: I think that is still possible with on-destroy hook, `ngOnDestroy() { // destroy session value }` Here this method will be triggered only when you're navigating away from page i.e. current component is destroyed. Can you give it a try and let me know?

Comment: No ngOnDestroy is not working for clearing session storage values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research understood that we cannot use router.events for absolute URL's and it triggers only for route changes.

I have used an alternative approach for whole functionality and not using session values anymore. So closing this question.